# Jasmine: define separate source file sets for Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tdd, jasmine

Separate parts of my site have separate sets of Javascript files, which -thrown all together- interfere with each other. In order to test everything with Jasmine, it seems I need some way to define separate sets of "assets" for different suites. Is this currently possible and if so, how?

Comment: Can you explain how they interfere with each other?  If you carefully place your Javascript in namespaces and check to see if each module in a namespace is already defined before you define it, you should be able to avoid conflict.  Perhaps if you give an example of a conflict, it can be shown how to repackage things to avoid conflict.  Rails 3.1 asset pipeline will expect (by default, anyway) you to be able to have all your javascript defined in one application.js (that is, all your modules roll up to a single file).

Comment: I had a JS file set for the public part of my site and one for the admin part. Both had a few functions and global variables with the same name, because they exposed similar behavior, but slightly different in both parts. What I ended up doing is: (1) factoring the common behavior into shared JS files and (2) implement [classes and inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to take care of the variants in behavior. So essentially I cleaned up the whole set of JS files so that they can all coexist at the same time. But I still see value in testing only subsets of files.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider, as suggested, breaking your javascript into different namespaces. One great way to make it easy to separate javascript into multiple files is by using the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) which uses closures and a few other neat properties of javascript to execute necessary code immediately, and contain it.

Comment: what if two js files define functions with the same name? In the web app, both wouldn't be loaded but with jasmine, they collide.

Comment: Apologies; I haven't used Jasmine before, but in general the above procedure is good for dividing javascript files. If there are two functions with the same name, they should probably belong to their own namespace / class.